# Unexpected Token in string version of valid JSON while performing JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, string, jsonparser

I am having problem converting a JSON String into Javascript object.

I ran into a few suggestions which said that I should not be using multi-line string but using single line string too did not work.

Snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/ankschoubey/hjh2d3z6/

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 4536`

Comment: pretty simple you have unescaped `"` in your string `"Farewell My Concubine,"`

Comment: In future, please place your code **here** in your question and not in a jsfiddle or any other external site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're including JSON as a JavaScript *string* value, you'll have to double-up on all the embedded backslash characters because they'll be parsed *twice*: first when the JavaScript parser reads the overall string constant to create the string value, and then again when you call `JSON.parse()`.

Thus that portion of the string with `\"` should be `\\"`. That way, the JavaScript string parsing will turn `\\"` into just `\"`, and that's what will make the JSON parser happy.